# Try to insert string to array to check if the string describe function

Tags: c, string

I have a string describing the function and I need to check if this is function
This idea came to me to put the string array then check

```
 the string: "1 11.1 2 3.2 3 44.1 4 5.4 5 7.4 6 1111.0"
```

the string describe the function (1,11.1),(2,3.2) (3,44.1) etc...

and I try to insert it to array like arr[0][0]=1 and arr[1][0]=11.1,arr[0][1]=2,arr[1][1]=3.2...
And i need help how to do it or get advice to another idea how to check If the string is function?I hope I explained myself better..thanks

in to example the string:

```
 "1 11.1 1 3.2 3 44.1 4 5.4 5 7.4 6 1111.0"
```

isn't describe function because we have (1,11.1) and (1,3.2) 
the question is how to insert the string into array

EDIT for clarity:

He is asking the following question:  Given a string of (apparently) evenly many floats, let's represent it in the form:

```
"x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 ... xn yn"
```

Then the string "defines a function" if for every `xi` and `xj` with `i` different from `j`, if the values at `xi` and `xj` are the same, then the values at `yi` and `yj` are the same.

He wants to know how to check whether a string "defines a function."

Comment: Could you write a part of expected array (cuz I dont get it :( )

Comment: I also assume you want to forge a matrix of numbers or something ?

Comment: i'm edit the question I hope now is better..
I just get a string and need to check if this is function according the examples

Comment: I dont get the examples. you have 2 dimmensions array -> but i dont get how do you assigning it , all I can offer is:

to go by the string , get the numbers and put them in to 1 dimmension array (as long as i dont get how you put it in to the matrix).

Comment: @user2957713,i just need to insert the string to char array

Comment: ooooooooh I guess I get it you want to make and array of char*
means and array of char array.

Comment: @user2957713,if the string is "1 2.3 3 44.3" I want to creat array in size 2X2 and arr[0][0]=1,arr[1][0]=2.3,arr[0][1]=3,arr[1][1]=44.3 (char array!)

Comment: @Andrey that's exactly what I want (your edit)

Comment: @Andrey nice edit -> makes all clear:)

Comment: @user2957713,yeyy:)),sorry on my bad English:\

Comment: it is ok , my Englais is worse :)

Comment: just a question , your string length is constant ?

Comment: ok , then gimme couple of minutes (I need coffee , and I will make u an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    {//split string by strtok, destroy input by strtok
        char input[] = "1 11.1 2 3.2 3 44.1 4 5.4 5 7.4 6 1111.0";
        char *array[10][2];
        char *item;
        char **to = &array[0][0];
        int i, count=0;
        for(item = strtok(input, " "); item != NULL; item = strtok(NULL, " ")){
            *to++ = item;
            ++count;
        }
        for(i = 0;i<count / 2;++i){
            printf("%s, %s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    {//convert double by strtod
        char *input = "1 11.1 1 3.2 3 44.1 4 5.4 5 7.4 6 1111.0";
        double array[10][2];
        double item;
        double *to = &array[0][0];
        char *p;
        int i, count=0, pairSize;
        for(p = input; *p != '\0';){
            item = strtod(p, &p);
            if(*p == ' ' || *p == '\0'){
                *to++ = item;
                ++count;
            } else {
                printf("invalid number\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        pairSize = count / 2;
        for(i = 0;i<pairSize;++i){
            printf("%g, %g\n", array[i][0], array[i][1]);
        }
        //Check the monotonic increase
        for(i = 0;i+1<pairSize;++i){
            if(array[i][0] >= array[i+1][0]){
                printf("invalid sequence at array[%d][0] = %g and array[%d][0] = %g\n", 
                    i, array[i][0], i+1, array[i+1][0]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```