# Insert string to double array

Tags: c, string

I got help here a few days ago in the construction of a function that gets a string of the like:

```
 "1 2.2 3 4.4 5 6.6 7 8.5"
```

and insert it to array[2][4] (in this case)  in the following form:

```
 1  | 3 | 5 | 7
 2.2|4.4|6.6|8.5
```

the function that do that the array is:

```
      //'function' is char*,'array' is double array

for(p = function; *p != '\0' ;p++){//convert double by strtod
    item = strtod(p, &p);
    ++div;

    if((div%2)!=0)
    {
        array[0][j]=item;
    }
    else
    {
        array[1][j++]=item;
        div=0;
    }   

}
```

the problem in the code that the function insert the values only to array[0][j] and not to array[1][j] the meaning the array seems like(if the array initialized to 0 in the begin):

```
 1  | 3 | 5 | 7
 0  | 0 | 0 | 0
```

the values insert only to the first line of the array,
if i call to the function with string:
     "0.5 2 1 4 3 6 0.5 8" 
so item always be 0 and i don't know why :\

The previous post:
[Try to insert string to array to check if the string describe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621859/try-to-insert-string-to-array-to-check-if-the-string-describe-function)
thanks

Comment: Run the code in a debugger and see where the index goes boom. Problem solved.

Comment: i try to do it,but if i call to the function with:
         "0.5 2 1 4 3 6 0.5 8" so item always be 0 and i don't know why :\

Comment: did you know that in the debugger you can follow the execution of your program line by line, check the state of the variables, etc... ?

Comment: sure,i think the problem is p don't know when the string function is end,i read the string from file with strcpy and maybe isn't set in the end of the string '\0'?

Comment: do you expect an answer for this? http://sscce.org

Comment: ok i think i find the problem thanks anyway on your time:)

Answer (score 3):

Initially, your code works. But then your pointer, `p`, is being incremented *past the end of the string* and you are seeing whatever is in memory after that, and overwriting the contents of your array. The problem is here:

```
for(p = function; *p != '\0' ;p++) {
    item = strtod(p, &p);
    // (other code)
}
```

After calling `strtod` for the very last number (8.5), the pointer `p` already points to the NULL terminator. But then, your for loop calls `p++` which increments it *one past the NULL terminator*. Your function continues running for some time after that, filling the array with garbage and possibly corrupting memory.

A solution is:

```
for(p = function; *p != '\0' ;) {
    item = strtod(p, &p);
    // (other code)
}
```

In this case, on most iterations, `p` points to the *space before each number*. That is okay, since `strtod` explicitly ignores whitespace. After the last iteration, `p` points to the NULL terminator and your loop ends before corrupting the array and possibly other parts of memory.

Dealing with pointers this way is error-prone. I’d recommend using the parsing facilities provided in the language, starting with `strtok()`.

Comment: when i replace my code in your code this is still not work

Comment: still,item is 0 ,p isn't stop in the end of the string

Comment: And you definitely removed the `p++` from the `for` statement?

Comment: Post your updated code above so we can look at it. As I said, using pointers in this way is very error-prone so there are likely other problems.

Comment: for(p = function; *p != '\0' ;){
  item = strtod(p, &p);
  ++div;
  
  if((div%2)!=0)
  {
   array[0][j]=item;
  }
  else
  {
   array[1][j++]=item;
   div=0;
  } 
  
 }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43458/discussion-between-nate-and-user2976686)